# Cancel recurring payment link in the receipt is missing

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, receipts, links, payment-method

When I enable 1 payment processor like stripe the cancel recurring payment link appears in the receipt. But as soon as I enable 2 payment processor the link disappears and only shows “this is a recurring contribution “. Anyone else faced this issue? How did you solve this? Thanks

Comment: did you figure anything out Tapash?

Comment: Issue resolved by itself in the latest upgrade of civi, stripe, GC extensions. I think it was an issue with core. Been a while, cant exactly recall what fixed the issue. sorry!